# HTML: trigger onerror twice to display the alternate of the alternate image

Tags: javascript, html, image, onerror

I'm in a situation where I know the name of an image, but not the exact extension. The extension could be .jpg or .png. Furthermore, the image itself might not even exist. So I have to perform the following:

1. Attempt to load image.jpg
2. Onerror, attempt to load image.png
3. Onerror, display notfound.jpg

I've written the following code:

```
<img src=image.jpg onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src=image.png;">
```

But "this.onerror=null" only stops onerror from going into infinite loop. How can I load the alternate of the alternative image, "notfound.jpg", when onerror is triggered again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have what i would do using jquery. I asked you if i could and you didn't reply.

So here it is.

Here would be the standard html:

```
<img src=image.jpg alt="" />
```

here would be the jquery attached to it:

```
$('img').on('error', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    // ajax with type 'HEAD' checks to see if the file exists
    $.ajax({
        url: 'image.png', //place alternate img link here
        type: 'HEAD',
        success: function () {
            //if success place alternate image url into image
            $this.prop('src', 'image.png');
        },
        error: function () {
            //if error place notfound image url into image
            $this.prop('src', 'notfound.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```

Here i have it working in a different environment but it shows the end product: http://jsfiddle.net/6nFdr/

Comment: Thanks! I tried to avoid jquery but it seems this is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

in the onerror return false after setting the image src.

example:

```
<img src="fake.png" onerror="this.src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9950cb3a6bdc0e10b1260135bd145e77?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'; return false;">
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/SKtVg/

you should avoid inline javascript btw. Not that it is incorrect, just less desired. 
If you didn't use inline js you could just have onerror run a small function to check for the other images and if they didn't load display a known to exist image.

Comment: could you explain how this helps? How is "notfound.jpg" displayed?